# mongo query with or operator and array element projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have these documents

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1468636149351, 
    "subject" : 1, 
    "likes" : [
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 1468677473954, 
    "subject" : 1, 
    "likes" : [
        1, 
        4, 
        3
    ]
}
```

I want to query by "subject" and "likes" and get all the subjects and the like element wether the like clause matched or not

e.g:if I query by "subject":1 and "likes":2 I should get

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1468636149351, 
    "subject" : 1, 
    "likes" : [2]
}
{ 
    "_id" : 1468677473954, 
    "subject" : 1, 
    "likes" : []
}
```

I tried :

```
db.collection.find(
        { $or: [ { "subject": 1} , { "subject": 1 , "likes": 1 } ]},
        {"likes.$":1})
```

but i get the error : positional operator (likes.$) requires corresponding field in query specifier

Comment: Just to confirm: are you trying to find all documents, which have _either_ `subject: 1` or some element of `likes` being 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this if you are okay with not returning `likes` array when the query doesn't match.

```
db.collection.find({"subject": 1},{"subject": 1, "likes":{$elemMatch:{$eq:2}}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the `$map` to project the documents in the way you have specified.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ 
    "$match": {
            $or : [
                {"subject": 1},
                {"likes":{$elemMatch:{$eq:2}}}
            ]
        }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "subject" : "$subject",
        "likes" : {
            "$setDifference": [
                {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": "$likes",
                      "as": "likes",
                      "in": {
                            "$cond": {
                              "if": {$eq : ["$$likes" , 2]},
                              "then": "$$likes",
                              "else": false
                            }
                          }
                    }
                },
                [false]
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

**Output :**

```
{ "_id" : 1468636149351, "subject" : 1, "likes" : [ 2 ] }
{ "_id" : 1468677473954, "subject" : 1, "likes" : [ ] }
```